# How to access JSON using d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Can't seem to find the answer to this question.

Does d3.js need the data to be in a particular format. For example:

```
var dataset = {
"people": [
  {
    "name": "person1",
    "projects": [
      {
        "name": "project1"
      },
      {
        "name": "project3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "person2",
    "projects": [
      {
        "name": "project1"
      },
      {
        "name": "project2"
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
};
```

And then using this:

```
d3.select('body')
.selectAll('p')
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append('p')
  .text(function(d){
    return d;
  });
```

Will not return anything.

Hope someone can help.

The docs and other tutorials all say you can use the above but always use the array as an example/demo.

Comment: The argument to .data() needs to be an array. See: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data

Answer (score 3):

As @MikeAtkins says you are trying to data bind the outer object. Try:

```
var dataset = {
"people": [
  {
    "name": "person1",
    "projects": [
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
 ]
};

d3.select('body')
.selectAll('p')
  .data(dataset.people)
  .enter()
  .append('p')
  .text(function(d){
    return d.name;
  });
```

If you want to bind to the NESTED arrays (i.e. each project for each person) you should see [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).